# Call javascript function on AutoHotKet

Tags: autohotkey

I have requirement to send information to third party tool and fetch some information from this tool using autohotkey.

but i am facing informaiton into textbox and try to fire button click event .

I have used this code to fill the textbox and fire button click event but not able for fire this because textbox event not fired as mention in below code..

```
pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("input")["rio-search"].focus()
pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("input")["rio-search"].value := startelemnet
fullvalue :=pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("input")["rio-search"].value
Sleep, 500
pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("input")["rio-search"].value := fullvalue
pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("input")["rio-search"].focus()
wbs.document.parentWindow.showOptions()
wbs.document.parentWindow.execScript("showOptions()")
pwb.document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").Click()

but i am try to call the javascript mehtod on textbox focus in autohotkey but not able to call :

<input type="text" id="rio-search" ng-model="$root.keywords" ng-focus="showOptions()" ng-blur="hideOptions()" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" placeholder="Search">

Please provide me the solution for this.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you even defined pwb and wbs?
Since your website seems to use angularJS, make sure you wait until the site is actually completely generated.
Also, it is likely not a function, but a method of the angular $scope.
So your js code might have to look somewhat like this:

```
var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
scope.showOptions()
```

But the method might expect some kind of "this" or similar of the input element. So I have no idea if this would work.

You might also wanna check:

```
xx.document.InvokeScript("functionName");
```